# android 4.2.2 loadurl webpage not displayed

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing application which loads url in webview.

The code is :

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
        web.resumeTimers();
        final WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.loadUrl(url);
```

class code

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

I have added permission INTERNET and done  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" but still it gives an error : webpage not available on android 4.2.2. I have checked internet connection also.

on other versions like 4.4.2 and 4.0.4 webpages are loading perfactly.

Comment: Welcome to SA, Did you receive any error in console/ log ? If yes, please include it in your question too.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution ??

Answer (score -1):

implement webView.setWebViewClient like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
        handler.proceed(); 
       }
});
```

}

it worked for me.